# Different time conversion by using java.util.Date in Java

Tags: java, java.util.date

I am using the below code for epoch to time conversion by using `java.util.Date` class in Java.

```
Long scheduledTime = 1602258300000L;
Date date = new Date(scheduledTime);
System.out.println("Date obj :" + date);
```

Below are the outputs while running the same code on two different timezone server :

On EDT server-

```
Date obj :Fri Oct 09 11:45:00 EDT 2020
```

On IST server -

```
Date obj :Fri Oct 09 21:15:00 IST 2020
```

Why does this happen? I am only passing milliseconds. This data is supposed to be treated as 21:15 on all servers. Why does Date class change the data?

Please share a sample piece of code for getting the same time data regardless of the timezone of the server.

Comment: Use `java.time` for this, this is one of the reasons for the introduction of that new datetime API (in Java 8).

Comment: Not so. The epoch is one point in time independent of time zone. so a count of milliseconds also denotes one point in time. In your case that point in time is Friday 9. October 2020 15:45:00. And at that point in time it was 21:15 in India and 11:45 on the east coast of North America.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    long scheduledTime = 1_602_258_300_000L;
    Instant pointInTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(scheduledTime);
    System.out.println(pointInTime);
```

Output from this snippet will be the same on all servers in all time zones:

> 2020-10-09T15:45:00Z

Since you want 21:15, specify the time zone for India:

```
    ZoneId serverTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = pointInTime.atZone(serverTimeZone);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

> 2020-10-09T21:15+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

### What went wrong?

The epoch is one point in time independent of time zone. so a count of milliseconds also denotes one point in time. In your case that point in time is Friday 9. October 2020 15:45:00 UTC. And at that point in time it was 21:15 in India and 11:45 on the East coast of North America. It’s a confusing trait of the outdated `Date` class that on one hand it represents just a point in time, on the other hand its `toString` method grabs the time zone setting of the JVM and uses it for rendering the string to be returned, thus giving you the false impression that you get different `Date` objects in different time zones when in fact they are equal.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Epoch & Unix Timestamp Conversion Tools](https://www.epochconverter.com/) where you can check what’s the equivalent of your milliseconds in UTC/GMT and in your own time zone.

Comment: I am with you. I would use the clean API of `java.time` to avoid any confusion and error.

Answer (score 10):

A `Date` object represents a specific instant in time, represented by a given number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

The `toString()` method converts that instant in time into a *local* time based on the default time zone. It's not that the `Date` value itself "has" a time zone - it's just `toString()` that uses the default one.

> This data is supposed to be treated as 21:15 on all servers.

That suggests you want to use the Indian time zone in all servers, at least when converting the instant in time for display. Without knowing anything more about your application, that's all we can say... other than "don't use `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar`; use the `java.time` classes instead". They're *much* better designed, and you're less likely to run into problems like this.

Comment: The user is suppose to enter the ```scheduledTime``` according to the server time zone. So, in our application, we assume that user already is sending the data according to the server timezone. No more offset addition is required on that data.

Comment: Can you share a sample code for achieving this using one of the ```java.time``` classes?

Comment: You should post a new question with more detailed requirements. I would suggest that forcing a user to handle the time zones and be aware of the server time zone is fairly unpleasant though. User shouldn't usually have to care at all where the server is, nor should the server's time zone affect the application at all.

Comment: Agreed. I am just looking for a workaround right now.

Comment: @Rishav Use `DateFormat` to control the timezone.

Comment: Please share a sample piece of code for the same. @Peter Lawrey

Comment: @Rishav: Again, *please post a separate question* instead of asking people to add information that isn't requested in *this* question.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by others you should now use the `java.time` package for working with time. If you look at the documentation of the `toString()` method of `java.util.Date`, it says that it coverts the Date object to a String of form:

> EEE MMM d m dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

It is like the following code is running in the background:

```
public String toString(){
    Date date=this;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat(
             "EEE MMM d m dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());  //This line is important.
    return simpleDateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Now, if you wanna format your Date object for a certain timezone you can do the same including setting the timezone:

```
Long scheduledTime = 1602258300000L;
Date date = new Date(scheduledTime);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat(
             "EEE MMM d m dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST")); 
String dateStr = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println("Date obj :" + dateStr);
```